# Graficar histograma de imagen LBP de gran tamaño?

Tags: python, matplotlib, inteligencia-artificial

A una imagen le calculo el descriptor LBP (Local Binary Pattern), usado para reconocer objetos.. y los pixeles quedan con valores entre 0 y 59.
Si es una imagen de mediano tamaño, grafica sin problemas.. pero al ingresar una de gran tamaño (por ejemplo de 3603x16517) obtengo un error que no sé a que se debe.

```
from skimage.feature import local_binary_pattern
from skimage.util import view_as_windows
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
import os
from skimage import util
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

lbp_radius = 3
lbp_n_points = 8 * lbp_radius
lbp_METHOD = 'nri_uniform'

image = io.imread('Mosaicos/Vitoco Corr.tif', as_grey=True)
image = util.img_as_ubyte(image)
lbp = local_binary_pattern(image, lbp_n_points, lbp_radius, lbp_METHOD)


plt.hist(lbp,59,[0,59])
plt.ylim([0,500])
plt.show()
```

Y obtengo el siguiente error:

```
/home/yehad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py:5882: UserWarning: 2D hist input should be nsamples x nvariables;
 this looks transposed (shape is 3603 x 16517)
  '(shape is %d x %d)' % inp.shape[::-1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no me equivoco, lo que se hace al representar el histograma tras aplicar **LBP** es en el `eje x` representar el valor de cada pixel y en el `eje y` el numero de pixeles absolutos o su porcentaje sobre el total.

El problema no depende del tamaño de la imagen, hay imagenes de 640 x 400 que ocasionan el mismo error. El problema  es que estas pasándole un array de dos dimenciones  para crear un histograma de una dimención. Si quieres usar un histograma 1D deberias pasarle un array unidimencinal que es lo que espera recibir `matplotlib`. Al recibir un array 2D trata de transformarlo en un array 1D y eso ocasiona el `Warning`, que por otro lado no evita que al final grafique algo.

Es decir `lbp` es una matriz de la forma:

```
lbp = [[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]]
```

Para solucionarlo puedes usar el método [`.ravel()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) de `NumPy`. De esta forma obtenemos el array unidimencional:

```
lbp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,]
```

El codigo sería:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from skimage.feature import local_binary_pattern
from skimage import io, util



lbp_radius = 3
lbp_n_points = 8 * lbp_radius
lbp_METHOD = 'nri_uniform'

image = io.imread('prueba2.tif', as_grey=True)
image = util.img_as_ubyte(image)
lbp = local_binary_pattern(image, lbp_n_points, lbp_radius, lbp_METHOD)

plt.hist(lbp.ravel(),59,[0,59])
plt.ylim([0,500])
plt.show()
```

Por ejemplo, con tu código la siguiente imagen de 640x400 me da el mismo error que a ti:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado usando mi modificación no genera ese `Warning` y obtenemos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias!
Justo me di cuenta de lo mismo, faltaba .ravel()
Genial, te pasaste.

Comment: Has sabido si es posible representar una cantidad X de valores lbp en una imagen? Así como un Thresholding a una imagen grayscale, pero en LBP. No está en la libreria oficial de Skimage ni OpenCV.

Comment: Hola @Yehadska primero te recomiendo que cuando una respuesta te sea útil o responda correctamente a tu pregunta la marques como aceptada para que otros usuarios que busquen la misma informacíón sepan que es correcta la solución, puedes mira como funciona [aquí](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas). No digo que marques la mia como aceptada solo que es una buena práctica a la hora de participar en [es.so] :). Dicho esto, no se si te he entendido bién, ¿Quieres visualizar la imagen para ver como queda al aplicar LBP?

Comment: Existe una posibilidad que es usar por ejemplo [`scipy.misc.toimage()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.toimage.html#scipy.misc.toimage) y guardar tu array como una imagen. No se si es esto lo que deseas hacer, es decir ver como queda la imagen tras pasarle el LBP (como si fuera un filtro). Si es asi es interesante el tema, si sigues con dudas puedes hacer otra pregunta donde es más facil contestar que aquí y asi se benefican otros usuarios con la misma duda. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por responder, no sabía lo de marcar una respuesta como aceptada, acabo de hacerlo. 
La segunda pregunta consiste en representar en color un rango LBP en la imagen original. por ejemplo, en este caso es un LBP uniforme (59 posibles valores para un pixel), 
lo resolví ayer, funciona bien, pero al representar algunos rangos, no lo hace y me muestra la imagen en grayscale solamente, es raro.

Comment: Aqui por ejemplo, coloreo de color rojo los pixeles que estén entre los valores 6 y 9 de LBP en la imagen original.

`def overlay_labels(image, lbp, labels):
    mask = np.logical_or.reduce([lbp == each for each in labels])
    return label2rgb(mask, image=image, bg_label=0, alpha=0.6)

labels = range(6,9)

imgplot = plt.imshow(overlay_labels(image, lbp, labels))

plt.show()
`

Comment: @Yehadska El código está bien según parece y "colorea" los pixeles que estan entre esos valores. Ten en cuenta el rango de valores que tiene el array `lbp`, por ejemplo para la imagen que pongo tiene 256000 valores comprendidos entre **0.0** y **554.0**. Para mi ejemplo solo hay 71 pixeles que tienen valores entre 6 y 8 (el 9 no se incluye si usas `range(6,9)`) y esos son los que marca en rojo.